# Angular - How to integrate Monaco Kusto to ngx-monaco-editor?

Tags: angular, monaco-editor, azure-data-explorer, ngx-monaco-editor

I want to add support for **Monaco Editor to support Kusto Queries**.  So, I tried to add `kusto` as a language to the Monaco Editor Options.  But, that doesn't work.

```
editorOptions = { theme: 'vs-dark', language: 'kusto' };
```

So, I googled and found `@kusto/monaco-kusto` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kusto/monaco-kusto).  I installed this package.  But, I don't know to integrate this package with Monaco Editor.  Their documentation looks confusing.  Can anyone please help me add the Kusto Language support for my Monaco Editor? I'm using Angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

`monaco-kusto` today is pretty hard to integrate because of 2 main reasons:

1. heavy use of web workers requires webpack config manipulations that usually are not available for people using products like `create-react-app`
2. language service is tranpiled from C# and the resulting code is not a module but a global import

If you just need syntax highlighting, you can try using the following textmate configuration in combination with  `monaco-textmate` npm package https://github.com/rosshamish/kuskus/blob/master/kusto-syntax-highlighting/syntaxes/kusto.tmLanguage

Comment: Hi Rony, Thanks for your answer.  I just want the syntax highlighting feature for Kusto Query.  Currently, I'm using `ngx-monaco-editor` package.  Do I need to replace it with `monaco-textmate`?  Can you guide me with the exact steps? I'm using Angular 9.

Comment: If I set up `monaco-textmate` in my module file means, how can I access it inside my component file? Can you please provide some Angular Example? Is there any way to add kusto support as the custom language to Monaco?